# SSRS Comma Delimited string to multiple hyperlinks

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, csv

I have a report in SSRS 2008. One of the columns may or may not contain a comma delimited set of values. An example of the data is:

```
string 1, string 2, string 3, string 4
```

It also might just have one value like String 1 and sometimes there's no value (Null).

Each of these strings can be hyperlinked via a 'parent' link; the parent link would stay the same and the string would just go at the end.

An example would be:

```
https://www.website.com/value=string1
https://www.website.com/value=string2
https://www.website.com/value=string3
https://www.website.com/value=string4
```

And so on; everything up to https://www.website.com/value= would stay the same as part of the parent hyperlink.

My current code for hyperlinking is as follows (allows hyperlinking when exporting to Excel):

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "RPL","javascript:void(window.open('https://www.website.com/value=" & Fields!String1.Value & "','_blank'))","https://www.website.com/value=" & Fields!String1.Value)
```

This works great if I only have one value in the field but would like to know how to code this expression to hyperlink if applicable:

1. multiple strings delimited by a comma.
2. only one string
3. null value (if null ignore and don't hyperlink)

Comment: Are you allowed to re-model your database to NOT store these strings in one comma-separated field (now that you see what a terrible idea it was)?

Comment: So the combined field is due to management not wanting duplicate entries/ wanted all the strings in one field - had to code it via SQL this way....but now they want to be able to click on a hyperlink for each.    Agree with the terrible idea and but can't adjust the database as it's fairly locked down.

Comment: No need for duplicate entries, just split the string values out into a separate lookup table with a foreign key back to the existing table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in the code section of your report properties:

```
Public Function Hyperlink(strString As string) As String

  If IsNothing(strString) Or strString = "" then
        Return Nothing
  Else

  Dim listarray() As String
  Dim output As String
  listarray = split(strString, ",")

  For i As integer = 0 To listarray.length -1

      output = output & "https://www.website.com/value=" & listarray(i).tostring.trim & vbnewline       

  Next

  Return output

  End If

End Function
```

and call it in your tablix expression with the following:

```
=Code.Hyperlink(Fields!YourField.Value)
```

and the value of the field is

```
Fields!YourField.Value = "string1, string2, string3, string4"
```

you will get:

```
https://www.website.com/value=string1
https://www.website.com/value=string2
https://www.website.com/value=string3
https://www.website.com/value=string4
```

If you put the expression `Code.Hyperlink(Fields!YourField.Value)` in the expression of your tablix **AND** in the function for select URL (Textbox Properties > Action > Go to URL), it will bahave in SSRS like a hyperlink.

**EDIT:**

Then encode your links with html tags. Change the function to this:

```
Public Function Hyperlink(strString As string) As String

  If IsNothing(strString) Or strString = "" then
    Return Nothing
  Else

  Dim listarray() As String
  Dim output As String
  listarray = split(strString, ",")

  For i As integer = 0 To listarray.length -1

    output = output & "<a href=" & Chr(34) & "https://www.website.com/value=" & listarray(i).tostring.trim & Chr(34) & ">" & "https://www.website.com/value=" & listarray(i).tostring.trim & "</a>" & vbnewline       

  Next

  Return output

  End If

End Function
```

Then click on your tablix textbox (click in the cell) then **Right Click > Create Placeholder... > Genaral** and check the **HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles**. And dont forget to delete the action expression. You dont need it anymore. The link action works now from the html tags.

Comment: Thanks this looks good but what it's doing now is incorporating the comma into the hyperlink so instead of the comma being the delimiter and 'unused' when I click on the link it opens like one large link: 
 
 
 
 https://www.website.com/value=string1%0D%0Ahttps://www.website.com/value=string2.  

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks this does work in delimiting each string into the respective hyperlink if applicable.  However on the web report itself, it returns the hyperlink instead of the value coming from SQL.   It looks like you mentioned above that's what I'd get but is there a way to display:

     'String1'

instead of

       'https://www.website.com/value=string1'

Comment: If you want to display the value change the line to: `output = output & "<a href=" & Chr(34) & "https://www.website.com/value=" & listarray(i).tostring.trim & Chr(34) & ">"  & listarray(i).tostring.trim & "</a>" & vbnewline`. This link shows how the `href` in html is builded. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

Comment: Yep that's it, this did the trick and working perfectly. thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you! I altered the underlying query of my report to produce the links complete with html tags as per this suggestion, inserted the placeholder as directed, and hey presto! +1

Answer (score 0):

Link 1
Link 2
Link 3
The above content will work for one cell of report viewer. Even it will works for PDF.  Download to PDF then click links it works.
But when Download excel then one cell has all three links. Click on 1st link it works, but when click on 2nd link it takes the 1st link only. and same happens for 3rd link also. 
I have tried in **excel to give link that we can do with help of hyperlink for one cell**. **But not for the text in cell.**
So excel not works as my knowledge in this case.

Comment: There is another accepted answers that provide the OP's question, and was posted some time ago. When posting an answer [see: How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.